# How to add dynamic fields in searchable block Sunspot solr model level rails app

Tags: sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

We have model 'ABC' has many association with model 'DEF'.

'DEF' model has fields "key" and "value"

So we want to define searchable block(sunspot solr) dynamically  for  model 'ABC' where we can define key as sunspot searchable block field and value is the data for this field.